# How do I get a character to enter a building in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, json, html, phaser-framework, tiled

I am making a top down RPG styled game using Tiled and Phaser 3. I have already made a map in Tiled for the city and store. Also, I have already set the game objects for the location of the store where the player is suppose to go in order to enter the store and the location where the player is supposed to appear. The thing I am having trouble figuring out the code I am suppose to use in order to facilitate this function, as well as going back to city map. One more thing, If there are any other ideas on how to go about this I am all ears.

Update: I got the character to load on the map with the function I already have but problem is that I can’t move my character.

Here is the function I have so far:

```js
// When the player walks into the store.
  player.onCollide = new Phaser.signal();
  Store.onCollide.add(enterstore,this);

  function enterstore(player){
  const map2 = this.make.tilemap({ key: "map2" });
   const tileset2 = map.addTilesetImage("store", "tiles2");

   const storeLayer = map.createStaticLayer("Tile Layer 1", tileset, 0, 0);

   storeLayer.setCollisionByProperty({ collides: true });

   this.physics.add.collider(player, storeLayer);

   storeLayer.setDepth(10);

   const SpawnPoint = map.findObject("Objects", obj => obj.name === "Spawn Point");
   const Store = map.findObject("Objects", obj => obj.name === "store");

   player = this.physics.add
    .sprite(SpawnPoint.x, SpawnPoint.y, "atlas", "misa-front")
    .setSize(30, 40)
    .setOffset(282, 202);

 };
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this is quite simple actualy. (Im not using Phaser, but the concept is the same)

In Tiled I put Rectangles in a seperate object layer. These rectangles cover areas that lead to a different location like doors, holes in the ground etc.
In the properties of the object I define a target location.

Code wise you simply check for collision with those rectangles. If the player collides with one of those you move him to the target location (seperate Tiled file or different coordinates on the current map).

Comment: This is really good advice thank you, I know that I must preload the map of the store but do I have to use the setCollisionByProperty in order to check for the collision of the object?